# Does Katalon Studio support hybrid apps automation and new browser version released?

Tags: ui-automation, katalon-studio

I am new to automation and doing POC on katalon studio. If anyone using katalon studio for UI automation. I have two questions:

1. Can you please tell me if Katalon Studio support hybrid app testing on Android and iOS (Mac or Windows)?
2. Does katalon studio automatically support the new released browser version or it takes time to get updated with new features of released version? Suppose I setup Katalon Studio and all latest versions are supported today, but suddenly tomorrow chrome browser releases new version. Does this auto support immediately?

Comment: Answer to your second question: Katalan Studio uses ChromeDriver, so you can update it with ease, when new Chrome version is released and driver version would be incompatible.

Comment: How do you mean "hybrid app"?

Comment: Hybrid app means - Not the native app...Hybrid apps are generally web apps created using cordova (in my case).

Comment: Thank you for answer to my second question. So with that answer, it seems that updating the ChromeDriver in Katalon is an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

- Mobile testing feature of `Katalon Studio` is based on `Appium`, which supports `Cordova`.
- Katalon Studio uses `ChromeDriver`, so you can update it with ease when the new Chrome version is released and the driver version would be incompatible.